# Using active record migrations on a .NET project

Tags: .net, oracle, activerecord, migration

I want to use the rails like database migrations on a .net project which uses an oracle database. Looking around at some of the frameworks like migratior.net (which apparently isn't well tested with oracle) I've decided to just try and use the rails active record as it looks like it's probably the most supported framework around.

My question is, if I just want to use the database migrations part from rails, do I have to install the whole rails framework or are there only certain packages I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of links:

[Dave Thomas discussing this](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2006/07/migrations_outs.html)

[Rails Migrations in non-Rails projects](http://gabrito.com/post/standalone-migrations-using-rails-migrations-in-non-rails-projects)

If you're okay with a slightly different approach, you could look at the [Oracle extensions](http://toadextensions.com/index.jspa) for the 'Data Dude' schema merging functionality in Visual Studio.